# Where we should put Tracking page tracking.aspx for Newsletter tracking?

Tags: outbound-email

Where we should put Tracking page tracking.aspx for Newsletter tracking? On multiple site or on a single site? As I have multiple sites. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the solution for single tracking web site.For that I have created a separate folder with tracking.aspx and .cs files. Then in each web site I have created a virtual directory and refer this folder. And In each publication's Audience Management tab paste this tracking.aspx path along with my web site. Its working for all type of tracking like email reading, email failed, Link Click both external and internal.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know and can see, you can store this page anywhere within your Tridion managed website, as long as you correctly reference its URL in your Synchronization Target (configured in the CME=>Administration tab=>Synchronization Targets).
The same synchronization target must be used for multiple websites, so you should be able to use that tracking page for multiple websites too.

Quoting the documentation:

> Blockquote
>   You can implement Contact Subscription and Tracking on multiple Web sites. To avoid synchronization errors, you must only create a single Synchronization Target for each Tracking database and Subscription database used on the Presentation Server. When Web sites share databases, you assign the same Synchronization Target to the concerned Publications.

Source: [SDL Online Documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-0BA06379-E166-4EE0-A00A-CF33B692EC2C)

On a side note you may want to store ChangeProfile.aspx, Confirm.aspx, Subscribe.aspx and Unsubscribe.aspx pages in Tridion and localize them or their corresponding template in the various language websites. This way you can translate the buttons text, labels and error messages.

Comment: Indeed -- you can put it where ever you want. I do want to point, though, that the tracking page is NOT supposed to be configured in the Synchronization Target (the TrackingSync page is). You only configure it on the Publication.

Comment: Hi Philippe/Peter, I have multiple site and I have created a main site for tracking only which contain tracking.aspx. I'm able to track mail opening, external link, failed tracking. But not able to redirect on internal component link URL . As on click of internal component link it redirect to the tracking site. It gives me url like www.mytrackingsite.com/mycomponentpage.aspx?tmcsTrackingInfo=$Jmdfg But I want www.myactualsite/mycomponentpage.aspx?tmcsTrackingInfo=$Jmdfg . This is my main problem if I host tracking page on  separate tracking site.